# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 15: invalid start byte when making a python executable

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I've got a tkinter GUI thats uses the following function:

```
def analyzeFile():
    x = fileEntry.get()
    df = pd.read_csv(x)


    for y in df.columns:
        df[y] = pd.to_numeric(df[y], errors='coerce')


    df = df.select_dtypes('number')



    correlation = df.corr()



    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('correlation.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer,'df')
    correlation.to_excel(writer,'correlation')
    writer.save()
```

When I go to make the python script into an executable with pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon = ccc.ico ccc.py --windowed in the command prompt, I get the error above.

I would like to turn my script into an executable successfully.

I've tried including an encoding='cp1252' parameter with different combinations my read_csv and to_excel lines. I know little about encoding though. I'm working on a windows machine.

Comment: try `encoding='latin1'`

Comment: On all three of the lines mentioned above? (read_csv and to_excels)?

Comment: That did not change anything. @PaulBrennan